# Reorder a list of objects for labels reporting across and then down

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik-reporting

I am trying to make a labels report (3 horizonal x 5 vertical) with Telerik Reporting. I have a list of objects (Customers with Code and Name). For example, the list have the items:

```
{ '001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008', '009', '010', '011', '012', '013', '014', '015' }.
```

I try this sample: https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/details/how-to-create-multi-column-report---across-the-page-and-then-down
But doesn't work for me, because I don't have any index field.

I bind the list to the report at runtime and in the preview, I get:

```
001     006     011
002     007     012
003     008     013
004     009     014
005     010     015
But I want to get:
001     002     003
004     005     006
007     008     009
010     011     012
013     014     015
```

I wanted to know if there is any method for linq to reorder the list grouping by the number of rows to get
001, 004, 007, 010, 013, 002, 005, 008, ...
Another problem is if the number of items is less than 15, I should fill the list with empty items.
Thanks.

Edit:
I'm trying something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int rows = 5;
        int columns = 3;
        List<string> x = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            var h = x.Where((c, index) => index % columns == i).Take(rows).ToList();
            foreach (var s in h)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> x = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };

        /*
         *                                                                  Begin in the label #5  
         * 001      006     011         =>  001     002     003         =>  ---     ---     ---    
         * 002      007     012         =>  004     005     006         =>  ---     001     002    
         * 003      008     013         =>  007     008     009         =>  003     004     005    
         * 004      009     014         =>  010     011     012         =>  006     007     008    
         * 005      010     015         =>  013     014     015         =>  009     010     011 ...
         * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         * 016                          =>  016     017     018
         * 017                          =>  019     020
         * 018                          =>  ---     ---
         * 019                          =>  ---     ---
         * 020                          =>  ---     ---
        */
        // Final list of strings or objects
        List<string> final = new List<string>();

        int firstPosition = 5;

        // Add empty items at the beggining
        for (int i = 0; i < (firstPosition - 1); i++)
        {
            x.Insert(0, "-");
        }

        int rows = 5;
        int columns = 3;

        int labels = rows * columns;
        int pages = x.Count() / labels + ((x.Count() % labels) == 0 ? 0 : 1);

        Console.WriteLine("Total labels {0}", x.Count());
        Console.WriteLine("Total labels per page {0}", labels);
        Console.WriteLine("Total pages {0}", pages);
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int page = 0; page < pages; page++)
        {       
            for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            {
                int r = rows;
                var h = x.Skip(page * labels).Where((c, index) => index % columns == i).Take(rows).ToList();
                foreach (var s in h)
                {
                    final.Add(s);
                    r--;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
                {
                    final.Add("-");
                }
            }           
        }

        foreach (var s in final)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

    }
}
```

I just need only the option to start in one position.

Edit:
Adding (firstPosition - 1) elements at the beggining of the list solve the start position:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (firstPosition - 1); i++)
{
    x.Insert(0, "-");
}
```

Example in .Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gh1t3S